# How to call a function parallelly in a while loop if a condition is met within the loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, multiprocessing, serversocket

I am creating a socket where the server creates a new log file daily. At midnight, a backup of the previous day's log needs to be taken. The log file is huge and it could take time to compress and upload it on the cloud. I don't want the server to wait until backup is taken before it continues to listen to new incoming requests. I have written pseudo code from the *'if'* condition in my code below as I am not sure how to implement it. I am guessing I'll have to use **multiprocessing** here?

```
while True:
    clientsocket, address = s.accept()
    enter_log("SUCCESS", "Established incoming connection from {}".format(address))

    if midnight:
        call_another_function_parallelly_for_backup_and_let_the_loop_continue_listening
```

Comment: I would spawn a thread to take care of the log backup. Alternatively,  use asyncio if you can convert your code. It's perfect for these kinds of applications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while True:
    clientsocket, address = s.accept()
    enter_log("SUCCESS", "Established incoming connection from {}".format(address))

    if midnight:
        t = threading.Thread(target=your_func, args=(your_arg,))
        t.start()
        t.join()

def your_func(your_arg):
    try:
       your logic
    except Exception as e:
       print(e)
```

This will create new thread until looping and  if is true...

Comment: Thank you it works. I also figured same can done with multiprocessing library as well. Which one do you think is the right tool for this job?

Comment: You welcome! works same but in you have more privileges in  threading..

Comment: Accept my answer that will help other..Thanks

Comment: Done, can you upvote my question too if you found it interesting to answer? :)